# telerik RadDatePicker Set date as string not as object?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I created a telerik RadDatePicker and I am able to set date inside textbox by creating a `var date = new Date() and using set_selectedDate(date)` method below is how I do it :

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Set Date" onclick="SetDate();" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function SetDate() {
                var date = new Date();
                var datepicker = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>");
                datepicker.set_selectedDate(date);
            }
        </script>
```

I need to pass date as string not as object for example `var date = "2016/11/11";`
 then pass the date string to the `datepicker.set_selectedDate(date);`

Comment: What you want is not clear. `set_selectedDate` takes a Date as Parameter.

Comment: what i want is to pass the date parameter as string to set_selectedDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
 function SetDate() {
   var datepicker = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>");
   datepicker.set_selectedDate(new Date('2016/11/11'));
```

}

Comment: i get Error by using the @Mehmet solution : TypeError: datepicker is null

Comment: @Mehmet thank you that work with me the null error was from my code .

Comment: If it is correct answer please check for right answer.